# Python - Consistent Labels

Tags: python

Some of the input values I have are lower case, and some are upper. For example, "female" and "Female" for gender. I need to process a series in a dataframe that has some inconsistent labels for classes.

How do I capitalize the values that are off - from "female" to "Female"?

Comment: You wrote "all to upper case" but your example "Female" is just initial upper case. All upper case would be "FEMALE". Which do you want? Also, do you understand the methods for strings in Python? Have you looked at the documentation?

Comment: I need to process a series in a dataframe, where there some inconsistent labels for classes. You are correct, I need to capitalize.

Answer (score 5):

Use the method `.upper()` or `.capitalize()` For example:

```
>>> 'female'.upper()
'FEMALE'
>>> 'female'.capitalize()
'Female'
>>> 'FeMaLe'.upper()
'FEMALE'
>>> 'FeMaLe'.capitalize()
'Female'
```

Another alternative would be to convert them to lowercase, using the `.lower()` method. This would make them all lowercase instead.

```
>>> 'FEMALE'.lower()
'female'
>>> 'FeMaLe'.lower()
'female'
>>> 'female'.lower()
'female'
```

Note that if the string already follows the format, all upper, capitalized, or all lower, no change is put on the string.

To change the value of the variable, make sure to include the `varname =` before it.

```
>>> a = 'female'
>>> a = a.capitalize()
>>> a
'Female'
>>> a = a.upper()
>>> a
'FEMALE'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `upper` method:

```
a = 'Female'
a.upper()
```

Comment: `a.upper()` alone won't do a thing. It will not change `a`.